# setInterval is not wroking

Tags: javascript

Trying to display the date, it only display one time then stops.

```js
var txtTime = document.getElementById('time');
var date = new Date();

var formatDate = function(d) {
  // Friday, July 03, 2020, 6:14:12 PM
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var minute = d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes();
  var seconds = d.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + d.getSeconds() : d.getSeconds();
  var date = d.getDate();
  var month = d.getMonth();
  var day = d.getDay();
  var year = d.getFullYear();


  return `${fDay(day)}, ${fMonth(month)} ${date++}, ${year}, ${fH(hour)[0]}:${minute++}:${seconds++} ${fH(hour)[1]}`;
}

function execDate() {
  txtTime.innerText = formatDate(date);
}

setInterval(function() {
  execDate();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<h1 id="time">Waiting...</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a variable `date` which holds the same value throughout. You need to pass the updated new date every time.

```
function execDate() {
    txtTime.innerText = formatDate(new Date());
}
```

or define the `date` variable inside the function

```
function execDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    txtTime.innerText = formatDate(date);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just had to put the date variable inside the function. And remove the parameter of the calling fn.